# why is my ubuntu 16.04 32 bit fresh install painfully slow?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, uefi, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have intel core i3 with 4GB ram and 2.4Ghz machine. Previously i was using Windows 10 to run Android Studio. But as its license experied i switched to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bit. But unfortunately its lagging very much for simple task only. I don't know what will happen if I start using Android Studio :(
Also do i need to upgrade to 64 bit? Or switch to any lower versions of Ubuntu like 14.04LTS? Or switch to Windows again. 
Specs--

- Os : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- RAM : 3.8 GiB
- Processor : Intel Core i3-3110M CPU @ 2.4GHz x 4
- Graphics : Intel ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
- OS type : 32-bit
- Disk : 488.1 GB

Please let me know if anyone faced similar problem. 
Also any further clarification needed to this question? [For graphic card detail i got this information from my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRIVp.png)

Comment: You really should use 64-bit Ubuntu instead. However, what mode is your disk set to in BIOS? What video drivers are you using? What video card do you have?

Comment: Again, 64-bit, and if you just installed then please install again 16.04 as there's no point in installing 14.04 to then upgrade. Install 16.04 64-bit from the start. But before check at UEFI (the replacement for old BIOS) and make sure the disk (or disks) are in AHCI mode. Then, after installing, you also need Nvidia proprietary drivers for optimal performance. You can find the proper driver in Additional drivers (unless you're card is brand new in which case you may need to add a PPA). Please edit and post your hardware specs, especially the exact model of the Nvidia graphics.

Comment: @dobey I just afternoon only i installed Ubuntu 14.04 and in evening upgrade to 16.04. No drivers yet installed. Although my laptop support Nvidia GeForce. From where I can check bios mode?

Comment: @dobey I just referred to this [UEFI docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)   found that my disk mode is "Legacy boot on HDD"

Comment: @CelticWarrior Sorry I just deleted my 1st comment by mistake(new on stackexchange) to which you referred. I tried finding model of Nvidia

Comment: Legacy boot is not the disk mode. You need to go to the SATA/IDE settings, and make sure the hard disk is set to AHCI mode.

Comment: @dobey yes, just found my hardisk is AHCI mode and UEFI mode is Enabled. shall i update this information in post?

Comment: @dobey Going to install ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64 from start. i will update here.

Comment: @dobey "Legacy boot on HDD" meant boot mode is "non-UEFI".

Comment: If this is a desktop system, you probably should _not_ install the server version (i.e: you should download the desktop version, and _not_ the version with `-server-` in the name.

Comment: @JonasCz I identified this mistake.... But after installing server version (lol). My whole laptop is working in terminal mode only. Will again install desktop version. Thank you for commenting :)

Comment: @pallavbohara I know what Legacy boot mode means. It has nothing to do with how the disk is accessed by the SATA/IDE drivers. I never said anythinga bout EFI mode. The open source drivers for your card might also not perform very well if you're using the NVidia only for graphics. Installing the proprietary nvidia drivers might help there, with perceived performance.

Comment: After using 64-bit os and Nvidia Proprietary driver my system is working great :) Thank you @dobey and JonasCz for such a in depth information and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using 64-bit os and Nvidia Proprietary driver my system is working great :) Thank you @dobey and @JonasCz for such a in depth information and help. And i am adding this line just to complete minimum word limit to answer on StackExchange.